# Will remain + 1st Form/ 3rd form?

Tags: grammar

An online Desk Review will be conducted which will start from 1st August and will remain continue/continued till 31st October.

Please assist me with this sentence. Thank you.

Comment: The phrase itself is a bit weird. Did you write it, or did you find it somewhere? What do you mean by *"will remain continue(d) till 31st October"*? Plus, it should either be **August 1st** or **1st of August**.

Comment: An online Desk Review will be conducted between 1st August and 31st October.

Comment: krobelusmeetsyndra, there is more than one correct way of writing dates, including "1st August".